# Managed ADB cannot detect devices via TCP

Tags: c#, android, adb, android-wifi

I'm currently using Madb for controlling my android devices. It does works really well over USB interface but when I change the listening port using the command

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

And in the AndroidDebugBride class in the Madb lib, I change the HostAddress to the DefaultGateWay of the Wifi Switch that is : 192.168.0.1.

I can connect, push, pull file to my device using the adb command:

```
adb connect 192.168.0.xxx
adb -s 192.168.0.xxx push yyy zzz
```

But the Madb cannot detect the devices, my initial code is

```
AndroidDebugBridge bridge = AndroidDebugBridge.CreateBridge("adb.exe", true);
List<Device> devices = bridge.Devices
```

I don't know exactly the problem since there isn't any documentation for madb.

Any helps would be appreciated

Comment: Have you solved it yet?

Comment: I just checked this in last night, once the nuget packages is updated those devices will be detected. You can read more about that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697068/accessing-android-devices-in-c-sharp).